# Google App Engine Tutorial : No Data Received

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I am trying to go through the Google App Engine Java tutorial. On [step 4](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/gettingstarted/ui_and_code), it says to add guestbook.jsp and run:

```
mvn appengine:devserver
```

All appeared to work fine, but when I tried to access http://localhost:8080/guestbook.jsp, the browser shows "No data received."  I also tried http://localhost:8080/ and http://localhost:8080/_ah/admin and got the same thing.

I tried creating guestbook.jsp on my own and also tried copying the phase 1 code from github.  Both yielded the same results.

Comment: Can you show us the screenshot of "No data received" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out.  I'm running on OS X and it appears something else is running on port 8080.  When I changed the port using:

```
mvn appengine:devserver -Dappengine.port=8888
```

I was able to access my server using http://localhost:8888/.